# Error in #'namespace/name_of_function

Tags: clojure, compiler-errors

I am doing a project in Clojure. When I run the program I get an error:

```
#'targil4_2_new.core/writeAndNext
```

Where `targil4_2_new` is the name of my namespace and `writeAndNext` is the name of a function in this namespace.

How do I know what the problem is?

Comment: How are you running the program? Is there anything else to the error? Can you include some relevant code?

Comment: What you posted is the representation of [`var`](http://clojure.org/vars)s as strings, not an error. As Diego suggested please post the code for your namespace and the way you are using the function.

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling your function?
Could you show me your trace error?

In your example you should call your function in this way:

1 -  require function namespace:

In REPL:

```
(require '[targil4_2_new.core :as xpto])
```

Or in your application:

```
(ns my-app.old-core
  (:require [targil4_2_new.core :as xpto]))
```

2 - call your function:

```
(xpto/writeAndNext ) //you can add your arguments
```